# After successful registration redirect user to index page and display popup

Tags: php

```
    if (isset($_GET['success']) && empty ($_GET['success'])) {
            echo 'Thank you for registering your service with us!';
            } else {

    //if no errors register user
    if (empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true) {

        $daysavailable='';
        foreach ($_POST['DaysAvailable'] as $value)
        {

        $daysavailable .=$value." ";

        }

        //$test = "Monday, Tuesday";
        $register_info= array (
            'MemberID'  => $_POST['MemberID'],
            'OddJobName'    => $_POST['OddJobName'],
            'Description'   => $_POST['Description'],
            'DaysAvailable' => $daysavailable,
            );
        register_job($register_info);
        if(success){
        echo"<script type=\"text/javascript\">".
            "alert('success');".
            "</script>";
        exit ();
    } else if (empty($errors) === false){
        //otherwise output errors
        echo output_errors($errors);
    }
    }
```

Looking at previous posts I changed my code to add:

```
  if(success){ //ADDED CODE
            echo"<script type=\"text/javascript\">".
                "alert('success');".
                "</script>";
```

Full code:

```
      if (isset($_GET['success']) && empty ($_GET['success'])) {
            echo 'Thank you for registering your service with us!';
            } else {
    //if no errors register user
    if (empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true) {

        $daysavailable='';
        foreach ($_POST['DaysAvailable'] as $value)
        {

        $daysavailable .=$value." ";

        }


        $register_info= array (
            'MemberID'  => $_POST['MemberID'],
            'OddJobName'    => $_POST['OddJobName'],
            'Description'   => $_POST['Description'],
            'DaysAvailable' => $daysavailable,
            );
        register_job($register_info);

        if(success){ //ADDED CODE
        echo"<script type=\"text/javascript\">".
            "alert('success');".
            "</script>";

        exit ();
    } else if (empty($errors) === false){
        //otherwise output errors
        echo output_errors($errors);
    }
    }
```

Now I get a pop up, but on the same page and 'success' is an undefined consent.

What I want to happen is that when the user registers successfully they are redirected to index.php and when this page opens I need a pop up to display telling the user they have registered successfully.

I'm not great with PHP (thats probably clear from the above) so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your registration page do

```
  if ($success) {
    header('Location: index.php?success=true');
  }
```

In your index.php

```
 if ($_GET['success']) {
      echo"<script type=\"text/javascript\">".
            "alert('success');".
            "</script>";
  }
```